# How to sent imagedata with ImagePicker Controller using swift 4

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uiimagepickercontroller, swift4

[image]I have `tabbarController` and `CameraViewControlle`r. I want to show the camera after clicking on camera tab. I have done it. after open the camera i want to show that particular image selected to the next `viewController`, but unable to do it. i am using `UIImagePickerController`, please help

```
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {
    let tabBarIndex = tabBarController.selectedIndex
    if tabBarIndex == 0 {
        //do your stuff
        print("First Tab")
    } else if tabBarIndex == 1 {
        print("Second Tab")
    } else if tabBarIndex == 2 {
        //do the camera stuff here
        let imagePickerController1 = ImagePickerController()
        imagePickerController1.delegate = self
        imagePickerController1.imageLimit = 2
        present(imagePickerController1,animated: true,completion: nil)
        print("camera")
        print("Third Tab")
    }     
}
```

**Done button pressed code.**

```
func doneButtonDidPress(_ imagePicker: ImagePickerController, images: [UIImage]) {
    let firstVC = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CameraVC") as! CameraVC

    show(firstVC, sender: nil)   
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    print("done")
}



func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    if let image = info["UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"] as? UIImage {

    }
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: what is `show(firstVC, sender: nil) `?

Comment: Hello kuldeep sir. that is to show the CameraViewController

Comment: you can move selected image to next `ViewController` from `UIImagePickerController` `delegate`.

Comment: sir will you please elaborate

Comment: When you pick image from `UIImagePickerController` than `func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any])` method call so you just have to pass selected image from here.

Comment: Just like this `func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    if let image = info["UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"] as? UIImage {
       let firstVC = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CameraVC") as! CameraVC  
       firstVC.image = image
   }
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}`

Comment: okay sir trying it

Comment: then what will write in done button sir?

Comment: this function i am talking about  func doneButtonDidPress(_ imagePicker: ImagePickerController, images: [UIImage]) {}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169667/discussion-between-gorib-developer-and-kuldeep).

Comment: @Kuldeep sir i have a question regarding this matter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `doneButtonDidPress` method is implemented in `TabBarController` and you want selected `Images` in `CameraVC` so do 1 thing add `NotificationCenter` in `CameraVC` and Post that notification with `Images` `array` once you done with `Image` pick. and load selected `images` from that `array` in `CameraVC`.

**CameraVC**

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(updateSelectedImages(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "updateSelectedImages"), object: nil)


@objc func updateSelectedImages(_ notification: Notification) {
    let imagesInfo = notification.object as? NSDictionary

    self.arrImages = imagesInfo?.value(forKey: "selectedIamges") as! [UIImage]
    self.imageView.image = self.arrImages[0]
    self.imageView1.image = self.arrImages[1]
}
```

**UITabBarController**

```
let dict = NSMutableDictionary()
dict.setValue(images, forKey: "selectedIamges")
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name("updateSelectedImages"), object: dict)
```

Comment: sir    self.imageView.image = self.arrImages[0] if the user select only one image then it is getting crashed. how to handle sir

Comment: If you have only 2 images to pick than you can do this using for loop or you can also do this by checking array count.

Comment: kuldeep Sir i have a question. are you there sir?

Comment: @GoribDeveloper, what's your question?

Comment: sir have a question regarding the image Data.are you there?\

Comment: @GoribDeveloper, what's your question?

Comment: @GoribDeveloper, that's great.

Comment: sir Are you there? i have a question.

Comment: @GoribDeveloper, whats  your question?

Comment: sir i want to send image from one view controller to another view controllers array. so that i can display the images from array to collectionview. how to do that sir?

Comment: @GoribDeveloper, Define 1 array in your 2nd `ViewController` and pass your image `array` from 1st `ViewController` like vc.arrImages = self.arrImages

Comment: okay sir, self.arrImages  means i have to take array in firstvc also. how to put the particluar image on the array of firstVc sir. i am using imagePickerController

Comment: @GoribDeveloper, let's discuss in chat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170059/discussion-between-gorib-developer-and-kuldeep).

Comment: sir are you there?

Comment: hi how can I help you?

Comment: sir i am using mmdrawer controller for a rightMenuVC. That is my Filter screen. I want to sent data to homeVC after user tapped on the button which is in RightMenuVC but unfortunately i am not getting the button tap event of rightMenu Vc in homeVC

Comment: without screen how can I guide you?

Comment: if i upload the screen shot ?

Comment: upload it, I will try to help you out.

Comment: Okay sir.i am uploading it

Comment: i have uploaded the screen shot sir

Comment: this piece of code written in the button of RightViewVC

Comment: let appdelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        
        appdelegate.drawerController?.closeDrawer(animated: true) { (isCompleted) in if let objTabbar = appdelegate.drawerController?.centerViewController as? TabBarController {
                
                if ((objTabbar.selectedViewController as? HomeVC) != nil){
            self.delegate?.filterValue(filterData: "jache ki?")
      
                }
            }

Comment: code not like this, we doesn't able to help you by this, we need to debug why it's not working so for that you need to send demo project.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177008/discussion-between-gorib-developer-and-kuldeep).